The Pronunciation of "Lyre"
I've spent most of my life pronouncing "Lyre" as "Lear" and have only just recently learned that in English it's actually pronounced "Liar", and I find that confusing. "Lyre" is supposed to come from the Greek "λύρα" which, from what I've found, sounds like "Lear-ah". English pronounces "Lyric", which come from the Greek "λυρικός" which comes from the same Greek word for Lyre, as "Lear-ik". And other languages like French continue to pronounce it "Lear".
So, why do we pronounce "Lyre" as "Liar" instead of "Lear" in English?

According to Merriam-Webster both lyre and liar can be pronounced in 2 ways. Andsources say lyre is from Latin (they took it from Greek, but it's possibly non-PIE in origin), which is a partial explanation.

Lyre rhymes with tyre, byre, pyre...

< French lyre, Old French lire (12th cent. in Littré), < Latin lyra, < Greek λύρα. (from OED)

Except for words that were recently borrowed from other languages, etymology tends to have little influience on modern pronunciation. Spelling is much more influential, and "lyre" looks like it should be pronounced as if it were written "lire".
